# Trying to make more simple VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have few models like this below for diferent tools i manage. I am trying to clean/improve the code... Could you help me?

All the informations comes inside columns B to N, and the column P concatenate it with ";". There are 6 sheets i do the same thing.

Any ideas to have a better performance and cleaner code?

```
Private Sub bov_mobile()
Sheets("Mobile").Select
Columns("p").Clear
fim = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To fim
Range("A" & i).Select

    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = "BOV" Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = "BOV BMF" Then
        Range("P" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-14]&"";""&RC[-13]&"";""&RC[-12]&"";""&RC[-11]&"";""&RC[-10]&"";""&RC[-9]&"";""&RC[-8]&"";""&RC[-7]&"";""&RC[-6]&"";""&RC[-5]&"";""&RC[-4]&"";""&RC[-3]&"";""&RC[-2]&"";"""
        Range("P" & i).Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next i

    ' ###############  ORDER BY
    Range("p2", Cells(Rows.count, 16).End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("P2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Range("P2", Cells(Rows.count, 16).End(xlUp)).Copy

Sheets("Mod_Bov").Select
Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, better for CodeReview - but may I suggest first [avoid using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what your code does without actually analyzing it - please [edit] your title to tell us what the code is doing (all questions on this site want to achieve simpler/better code) - thanks, and welcome to CR!

Answer (score 5):

The quickest fix you can make to improve speed is removing all of the `Select` statements, and instead just referencing those selected ranges with variables. (`Select` slows down any VBA code significantly).  You can also toggle `Application.ScreenUpdating` to False before the code and True after to gain run-time speed.

Comment: The screenUpdating is = false inside the sub that call this one. The main sub calls bov_mobile, bov_xxx, bov_xxx2 and etc...
I will try to avoid the select... Im doing first steps.. :)

Answer (score 4):

The main problem here is the use of .Select. There's no need to select the cells in order to manipulate them. It forces the GUI to update which is a very slow operation in Excel and it also causes Selection Change events and similar code to fire in the background. Simply perform the action on the cells directly. So, for example this:

```
Sheets("Mobile").Select
Columns("p").Clear
```

Should be changed to this

```
Sheets("Mobile").Columns("p").Clear
```

The same with your loop. Avoid this

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value
```

In favour of this

```
Cells(i,22).Value
```

Column 22 is 14 columns from column I. This increases efficiency in two ways: by not selecting the cell and also by avoiding the unnecessary calculation carried out by the Offset function.

Comment: @absinthe Ty! I got your point, but i call this sub from other sheet, so i have to move to it  and start its routines.

Comment: When you use `Sheets("Mobile")` the VBA code will reference the sheet "Mobile" _no matter what sheet is currently visible_ in the user interface without having to `.Activate` or `.Select` it. That's the beauty of explicitly referencing `Workbooks()` or `Worksheets()` (or `Sheets()`).

Answer (score 4):

### First, things that jump out at me:

---

`Private Sub bov_mobile()`

Don't use `_` in Sub/function names. In VBA, `_` in a method name denotes an event-triggered Method E.G. `Workbook_Open` or `Button_OnClick` so avoid it in your own method names.

---

**`Option Explicit`**

That should be at the top of every VBA module you ever write. It requires you to declare variable names before you use them. E.G. `Dim i As Long`. This makes sure that you **can't** do something like this:

```
Dim fim As Long
fim = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to fin ' <-- Typo
```

Because the compiler will ask why `fin` hasn't been declared as a variable. Simple typos like that are a real pain, so don't give them a chance to appear in your code in the first place.

---

### Use the Object Model

VBA has objects for everything. `Workbook`s, `Worksheet`s, `Range`s etc. Rather than something like this:

```
Sheets("Mobile").Select
Sheets("Mobile").Range("A" & i).Select
Sheets("Mobile").Range("P" & i).Copy 
Sheets("Mobile").Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues
```

You should instead:

```
Dim mobileSheet As Worksheet
Set mobilesheet = Sheets("Mobile")

mobileSheet.Select
mobileSheet.Range("A" & i).Select
mobileSheet.Range("P" & i).Copy 
mobileSheet.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues
```

And then:

```
Dim mobileSheet As Worksheet
Set mobilesheet = Sheets("Mobile")

With mobileSheet

    .Select
    .Range("A" & i).Select
    .Range("P" & i).Copy 
    .Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues

End With
```

And then:

```
Dim mobileSheet As Worksheet
Set mobileSheet = Sheets("Mobile")

With mobileSheet

    Dim pasteCell As Range
    Set pasteCell = .Range("A" & i)

    Dim copyCell As Range
    Set copyCell = .Range("P" & i)

End With

With CopyCell

    .FormulaR1C1 = ....
    .Copy

End With

pasteCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Notice how there are no `Select`s. There are no `Active`s. There are no `Offset`s. Everything is descriptively named.

**Your sub using proper objects and better naming:**

```
Private Sub bov_mobile()

    Dim mobileSheet As Worksheet
    Set mobileSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mobile")

    Dim bovSheet As Worksheet
    Set bovSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mod_Bov")

    mobileSheet.Columns("P").Clear

    Dim finalRow As Long
    With mobileSheet
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim baseCell As Range
    Dim copyCell As Range
    Dim columnOffset As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    For currentRow = 2 To finalRow

        With mobileSheet
            Set baseCell = .Cells(currentRow, 1)
            Set copyCell = .Cells(currentRow, 15)
        End With

        With copyCell
            If .Text = "BOV" Or .Text = "BOV VMF" Then
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-14]&"";""&RC[-13]&"";""&RC[-12]&"";""&RC[-11]&"";""&RC[-10]&"";""&RC[-9]&"";""&RC[-8]&"";""&RC[-7]&"";""&RC[-6]&"";""&RC[-5]&"";""&RC[-4]&"";""&RC[-3]&"";""&RC[-2]&"";"""
                .Copy

                baseCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        End With

    Next currentRow

    Dim sortRange As Range
    With mobileSheet

        Set sortRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 16), .Cells(finalRow, 16))

        sortRange.Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, 16), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    End With

    sortRange.Copy

    Dim bovFinalRow As Long
    With bovSheet
        bovFinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    bovSheet.Cells(bovFinalRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Much, much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet.

Answer (score 3):

I'd add my 0.02 cents

---

**Pasting Values**

it's always much faster to use

```
Range1.Value = Range2.Value
```

provided `Range1` and `Range2` have the same size

---

**Avoiding formulas**

they mean writing into cells which is a time consuming activity, and possibly raise sheet calculation

the following code:

```
"=RC[-14]&"";""&RC[-13]&"";""&RC[-12]&"";""&RC[-11]&"";""&RC[-10]&"";""&RC[-9]&"";""&RC[-8]&"";""&RC[-7]&"";""&RC[-6]&"";""&RC[-5]&"";""&RC[-4]&"";""&RC[-3]&"";""&RC[-2]&"";"""
```

can be substituted with:

```
Join(.Offset(, -13).Resize(, 14), ";")
```

---

**Avoid `With` inside a loop**

you have such code

```
For currentRow = 2 To finalRow

    With mobileSheet

    ...
Next currentRow
```

which means that a reference to `mobileSheet` is made at every loop

so just take it outside the loop:

```
With mobileSheet
    For currentRow = 2 To finalRow
        ....
    Next currentRow
End With
```

adjusting what necessary

---

**Use `With`**

to lessen memory charge in referencing the same object multiple time

so that:

```
With mobileSheet
    For currentRow = 2 To finalRow
        ....
    Next currentRow
End With

Dim sortRange As Range
With mobileSheet

    Set sortRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 16), .Cells(finalRow, 16))

    sortRange.Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, 16), Order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End With

sortRange.Copy
```

becomes

```
With mobileSheet
    For currentRow = 2 To finalRow
        ....
    Next currentRow

    With .Range(.Cells(2, 16), .Cells(finalRow, 16))
        .Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, 16), Order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        .Copy
    End With
End With
```

---

**Summary**

all what above can lead to the following refactoring of `Sub bov_mobile()`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub bov_mobile()
    Dim currentRow As Long, finalRow As Long
    Dim mobileSheet As Worksheet: Set mobileSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mobile")
    Dim bovSheet As Worksheet:  Set bovSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mod_Bov")

    With mobileSheet
        .Columns("P").ClearContents '<-- ClearContents() is faster than Clear(), if you don't bother formatting
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For currentRow = 2 To finalRow
            With .Cells(currentRow, 15)
                If .Text = "BOV" Or .Text = "BOV VMF" Then .Parent.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value = Join(.Offset(, -13).Resize(, 14), ";")
            End With
        Next currentRow

        With .Range(.Cells(2, 16), .Cells(finalRow, 16)) '<-- this is your "SortRange"
            .Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, 16), Order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlGuess, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

            bovSheet.Cells(bovSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```